# Transact SQL how to flag a person_id whenever the grad changes (promotions)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a column to flag employees whenever they get promoted (change in GRADE) like the below example :

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+------+
| PERSON_ID | DATE_START |  DATE_END  | GRADE | Flag |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+------+
|       614 | 12/12/2012 | 12/12/2013 |     3 |    0 |
|       614 | 12/12/2013 | 12/31/2013 |     3 |    0 |
|       614 | 1/1/2014   | 5/31/2015  |     2 |    1 |
|       616 | 2/1/2009   | 12/31/2011 |     4 |    0 |
|       616 | 1/1/2012   | 12/31/2012 |     4 |    0 |
|       616 | 1/1/2013   | 12/31/2016 |     2 |    1 |
|       616 | 1/1/2017   | 12/31/4712 |     1 |    1 |
|       617 | 2/26/2012  | 12/31/2012 |     5 |    0 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for a trigger.

Comment: You've only supplied what your end goal is here. We don't have any original data to work on. What does your data look like before hand? Please edit your post to include **DDL** and **consumable sample data** (in the format in an `INSERT` statement). At a guess, this looks like a gaps and Island question.

Comment: [This](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) is how you do tables. (Or better yet, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` for reproducibility.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this approach if you want the date where the new grade gets valid: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba18c/3/0

or this if you want the last date with the old grade flagged: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba18c/4/0

Here the second approach a bit more detailed:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  PERSON_ID int
  ,DATE_START date
  ,DATE_END date
  ,GRADE int
 )

 INSERT INTO @t
 VALUES
 (414         ,'12/12/2012'  ,'12/12/2013'  ,3)
,(414         ,'12/12/2013'  ,'12/31/2013'  ,3)
,(414         ,'1/1/2014'    ,'5/31/2015'   ,2)
,(616         ,'2/1/2009'    ,'12/31/2011'  ,4)
,(616         ,'1/1/2012'    ,'12/31/2012'  ,4)
,(616         ,'1/1/2013'    ,'12/31/2016'  ,2)
,(616         ,'1/1/2017'    ,'12/31/4712'  ,1)

SELECT *
      ,CASE
         WHEN grade != ISNULL(LEAD(grade) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_start), grade) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS Flag
  FROM @t
  ORDER BY person_id, date_start
```

The trick is to compare the current grade with the next grade of the same person. This is done by the `LEAD()` and the `PARTITION BY`. In order to compare in the correct order, you have to add the `ORDER BY`. Last but not least: the `IS NULL`is required in order to correctly consider the last record of the current person - `LEAD` will provide NULL if no more records are found for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this .

```
SELECT * INTO #YourTable FROM
(
SELECT  614 PERSON_ID, '12/12/2012' DATE_START, '12/12/2013' DATE_END, 3 GRADE UNION ALL
SELECT  614 , '12/12/2013' , '12/31/2013' , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT  614 , '1/1/2014'   , '5/31/2015'  , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  616 , '2/1/2009'   , '12/31/2011' , 4 UNION ALL
SELECT  616 , '1/1/2012'   , '12/31/2012' , 4 UNION ALL
SELECT  616 , '1/1/2013'   , '12/31/2016' , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  616 , '1/1/2017'   , '12/31/4712' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  617 , '2/26/2012'  , '12/31/2012' , 5
) AS A

-- *** Query *** ---

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *,LAG(GRADE)OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))LAG FROM  #YourTable
)
SELECT PERSON_ID , DATE_START ,  DATE_END  , GRADE,
CASE WHEN GRADE=ISNULL(LAG,GRADE)THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS FLAG FROM CTE
```

Comment: Two things which should be changed: on the one hand side it's not good practice to use reserved words as alias (such as LAG in your query). On the other hand side the `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` gets broken as soon as other records are inserted which dates earlier than the existing records. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a40e6/1/0 for an example

Comment: ok @Tyron78 thanks for pointing my mistakes .i will follow what you have suggested .